# i need to mass install fast using only usb thumb drives

Tags: usb-installation, automatic

hi is there a way to automate the install of the latest ubuntu desktop install with only a usb drive because I need to mass install. I have looked into it but only saw that you can host a server that will auto install don't have a way to host a server and auto install from a server.

Comment: Consider an USB SSD. I can do full install of Kubuntu in 12 to 15 minutes. Install from flash drive is 40 min or more. I then run scripts to configure & restore from my backups. You can configure one system & store those customization  as a backup on SSD. Then rsync into new install each time.  There are a variety of questions on creating auto install scripts, but only worthwhile if a lot of systems. And install scripts seem to change with different versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: I don't see why install from USB flash drive can't be used; I'm involved in QA and am accustomed to full installs taking <3 minutes (*on good hardware with fast SSD*) not including the booting of the hardware (*boot time can differ significantly too*), ~<2 mins 15 secs for some hardware.  I didn't consider that as *slow* using the defaults & wonder how many you are installing that requires faster?